# Insert an array in a column with type jsonb in postgres using golang sqlx

Tags: postgresql, go, psql

When I create and store using the below logic, it creates an object. What I want to create is an array of objects and I want to handle this on the server side and not force the UI to send me an array of objects, in which case it does get saved as an array of objects

```
sqlstatement := `INSERT INTO TABLE (THREAD) VALUES ($1);`  
tx.MustExec(sqlstatement,t.Thread)

type Create struct {
    Thread  json.RawMessage `json:"thread"`
}
```

The created JSONB object is of type

```
{
    thread: {
        data: temp
    }
}
```

What I am looking to create is:

```
{
    thread: [{
        data: temp
    }]
}
```

Comment: `json.RawMessage` able to retrieve both object and array of objects

Comment: Yes. But t.TicketThread is saved as on object. I want to save it as an array of objects

Comment: can you show me what is the scheme of struct `TicketThread`?

Comment: And how is `t.TicketThread` defined?

Comment: tx.MustExec(sqlstatement,t.Thread)

Comment: not that. can paste the code of struct that create object `t` ?

Comment: If the raw message is an object then it's gonna store an object, if you want to store an array instead, then make it an array. https://play.golang.com/p/zCDO32X_m6Q

Comment: @xpare I have edited the question. It should make sense now i think

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks that solved the issue :)